# capacitive soil moisture sensor connected to attiny85

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, sensor, attiny, interface

je suis en cours de créer une circuit électronique d'un capteur d'humidité du sol capacitif avec un aop pour amplifier le signal sortie de capteur , et ce capteur relie avec le microcontrolleur attiny85 qui est aussi comprend 2 interface l'un pour la programmation j'utilise le connecteur 6 broches ISP et l'autre pour la communication I2C j'utilise un connecteur de 4 broches . ma probléme ici est ce que il y a des connecteur qui ne sont pas utilisé dans cette circuit ?

Google translation:

> I am in the process of creating an electronic circuit for a capacitive soil moisture sensor with an Op-Amp to amplify the sensor output signal, and this sensor connects with the attiny85 micro-controller which also includes 2 interfaces, one for programming, for which I use the 6 pin ISP connector and the other for I2C communication, for which I use a 4 pin connector. My problem here is that there are connectors that are not used in this circuit?

[image]

Comment: Which connections do you refer to? There is something wrong in the way R7 and R8 are connected. They should make a voltage divider feeding -IN of the OpAmp.

Comment: Do you talk about the half visible 10 kohm resistor between /RESET (PB5) and VCC at the top right border?

Comment: can you help me, this is my circuit for a solution for a capacitive soil moisture sensor connected with attiny85 which connects itself with two connectors for two interfaces one for I2C communication which is 4 pins and the other for the programming interface which is 6 pins, are there any proposals to reduce the number of connectors or are there any connectors that are not usable in this circuit?

Comment: @AydaBenayed - (a) Your original question, in French language, was translated by another user. Although well-intentioned, that should not have happened. Stack Exchange (SE) policy is [not to translate non-English posts into English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676) in case errors are introduced. Please review the English translation and [edit] the English text, if needed. (b) You seem to have added basically the same question as a comment. That is not the correct etiquette on SE. The whole question should be at the top of the page. Again, please [edit] that to make it clear & complete.

Comment: (continued) (c) Your question is not clear (at least to me). This is probably a translation problem and it just confirms the problems with translating questions. You seem to be asking about connectors. In your comment, you ask "*are there any connectors that are not usable in this circuit?*". You don't mean "not usable", but it's unclear what you do mean. I don't think you mean "not used", as *you* must know which connectors *you* need to use. It seems you have J1 (programming, 6-pin), J2 (perhaps that is for the sensor?, 3-pin), J3 (I2C, 4-pin). || What is your question, exactly? TY